# Function inside an Object inside a Class

Tags: javascript, json, class, object

I have a class and this class have a function.
I want to call that function from inside another function that is inside an object inside of that class.

Here is the code:

```js
class Animal
{
    constructor(name)
    {
        this.name = name
    }

    //This is the function i want to call from inside the object below
    emitSound(sound)
    {
        return `I am ${sound}`
    }

    //This is the object with functions
    actions = {
        eat()
        {
            return this.emitSound('eating');
        },
        sleep()
        {
            return this.emitSound('sleeping');
        }
    }
}

const animal = new Animal('Dog');

console.log(animal.actions.eat());
```

> (this code is just an example, the application im developing is way
> more complex)

How you can see, it returns an error saying that "*this.emitSound()*" is **undefined**.
Its happening because the function `eat()` is trying to call `this` from inside the actions object, isnt it?

So what I need is a way to call the `emitSound()` function inside the **actions object** functions. Please help!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because `this` refers to `actions` because you're calling it as a method of `actions`: `actions.eat()`.

One workaround is to [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the functions to the current instance in the `constructor`:

```js
class Animal
{
    constructor(name)
    {
        this.name = name
        this.actions.eat = this.actions.eat.bind(this);
        this.actions.sleep = this.actions.sleep.bind(this);
    }

    //This is the function i want to call from inside the object below
    emitSound(sound)
    {
        return `I am ${sound}`
    }

    //This is the object with functions
    actions = {
        eat()
        {
            return this.emitSound('eating');
        },
        sleep()
        {
            return this.emitSound('sleeping');
        }
    }
}

const animal = new Animal('Dog');

console.log(animal.actions.eat());
```

Other option: declare the functions as [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
class Animal
{
    constructor(name)
    {
        this.name = name
    }

    //This is the function i want to call from inside the object below
    emitSound(sound)
    {
        return `I am ${sound}`
    }

    //This is the object with functions
    actions = {
        eat: () => this.emitSound('eating'),
        sleep: () => this.emitSound('sleeping')
    }
}

const animal = new Animal('Dog');

console.log(animal.actions.eat());
```

Comment: It definitely solved my problem, use arrow functions worked perfectly. Thank you :)